# Strange behavior after installing GeForce GT 1030 card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

For about two years I’ve been using my Gigabyte GA-Z97M-D3H with onboard graphics on various Linux distributions and last year settled on Ubuntu MATE.

It worked fine, but I knew one day I’d have to get a dedicated GPU. So I got a NVIDIA GeForce GT1030 (the actual model is Gigabyte GV N1030SL).

I decided to do a fresh install and noticed right away that on various distros (I tried Ubuntu 17.10, Ubuntu MATE 17.10, Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and Kubuntu 16.04) when booting from USB various errors were reported on the screen. I did not get the actual messages, but they had something to do with UEFI and Nouveau. The installers loaded, but the resolution was 1024x768. I went various times until the end of the process hoping to load a proprietary driver after install, but the NVIDIA stuff that is loaded does nothing for me in this regard. I searched online and found some posts about the monitor not being able to inform the hardware the resolutions it is capable of, but the recommended utility to solve it was Windows-only and, on the Ubuntu versions I tried, NVIDIA X server settings doesn't offer me anything with regards to monitor. It just seems to find a generic monitor which can't be configured.

Then on Ubuntu MATE I tried switching from HDMI to DVI and at first it worked, but then I did a reinstall (for another, un-related reason), and it went back to 1024x768. I tried it all: messing with UEFI Setup, reinstalling hardware, installing other distros, all to no luck, until I reinstalled Ub Mate with low-res on HDMI and then turned it off, switched again to DVI, and then got 1080p automatically.

What bothers me is: first, the same way it came, it can go (stop working) for no apparent reason; second, the messed up installation. After it finished, on the “Remove installation media and press ENTER” screen, it was looking like there was a command line prompt on the background, with blinking cursor that jumped lines if you pressed enter and all. Needless to say, I had to actually push the reset button on the case to get the computer to restart.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Some further info on my system:
Monitor is LG 22MP55
Ubuntu MATE 17.10 (installed on SSD)
GA-Z97M-D3H, 8GB RAM
Intel Core i5 4690k

After this last install yesterday, I went to get some sleep e put the system on Suspend. When I got back to it, several hours later, after hitting the space bar to wake the system, the LEDs on the case lit up, but the monitor stayed as if receiving no signal until it went on power saving mode again. Had to hit the physical reset button and restart. Then I noticed that the startup Ubuntu MATE screen shows up in 1024X768 and only on the login screen we get to 1080p.

Comment: Did you get it to work?  I installed nividia-384 driver (by apt-get) and have had zero problems so far.

Comment: Actually it’s interesting that you showed up saying this now, because I just ran into further problems now that I did a fresh install of 18.04 (both regular Ubuntu and Ubuntu Mate). The current version of the driver is 390, if I’m not mistaken, but you’re saying that an older version - 384 in this case - worked for you. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Just to clarify, on 17.10 it ended up working. There various problems during install, but then I went with the nvidia proprietary drivers and it worked. Now, installing 18.04, sometimes the system doesn’t load, or gets into a login loop, or still keeps lagging (especially at the login screen) or quickly halting and coming back. I tried version 390 and then, by adding the ppa, 396 or something like that. If you confirm that 384 is the way to go, I’ll try it as soon as I find out how to chose a driver not listed in the update drivers tab.

Comment: Hi fmb, 384 just worked for me, haven't tried anything else (will go for 18.04 soon and we'll see than...).  I am afraid though that in your case there may be some sort of MB/card compatibility issues.  Had a terrible pain some years ago trying to get two radeon 6450s to be recognized.